# Is it possible to write an Alternative instance for Identity a if there's a Monoid for a?

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor

I'd like to write an `Alternative` instance for the `Identity` newtype. The skeleton isn't hard:

```hs
instance Alternative Identity where
  empty = _
  (<|>) = _
```

However, the implementation is impossible for all types. It would be easy if I have a Monoid instance for `a` though:

```hs
instance Alternative Identity where
  empty = Identity mempty
  (Identity a) <|> (Identity a') = Identity (a <> a')
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that I want to define the `Alternative` instance only for when the type inside has a Monoid instance? Since the `a` isn't mentioned anywhere, I can't just use a constraint `Monoid a =>`.

Comment: This is the essential difference between a `Monoid` instance for a type `F A` and an `Alternative` instance for `F`. `meppty` and `mappend` are (or at least might be) defined monomorphically with knowledge of `A`. `empty` and `<|>` work only with the structure of `F`, and **must** work exactly the same for all types `a` it might be applied to.

Comment: Read up on *constrained monads*; this would be a constrained alternative functor. See e.g. https://ku-fpg.github.io/practice/constrainedTypeClassInstances/ or https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2017-03-08-constrained-applicatives.html for starting points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `Alternative` must provide `empty` for *all* types `a`, with no restrictions. Otherwise, it does not fulfill the `Alternative` contract.

That is, if we have an instance `Alternative f`, we must have

```
empty :: forall a . f a
```

without any further constraints.

Hence, `Identity` is not an `Alternative`.

This is a known problem, found in many similar type classes. For instance, many would enjoy a `Functor Set` instance, but that would require

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
```

for all types `a` and `b`, while the function above can only be achieved on `Ord` types. Since we can't add the constraint, we do not get a functor.

Still, one can try using a more general type class that accounts for additional constraints. Maybe something like

```
class CFunctor c f where
   fmap :: (c a, c b) => (a->b) -> f a -> f b

class CFunctor c f => CApplicative c f where
   empty :: c a => f a
   (<*>) :: (c a, c b, c (a->b)) => f (a->b) -> f a -> f b
```

but these are not the "standard" ones in the library. (I guess on hackage there should be something similar to the constrained class variants above.)